# RXJS: Multiple Subscriptions in Order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've searched the web (StackOverflow, Rxjs, blogs, etc.) for an answer to my specific case, but I've not found anything for what I'm specifically looking for.

In my Angular component, I have the following:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
      if (!!params.page) {
        if (params.page <= 1) this.skip = 0;
        else this.skip = (params.page - 1) * this.limit;
      }
    });
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      this.filter = params.filter;
      this.term = params.term;
      this.year = params.year;
      this.month = params.month;
    });
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.setProvider(data.route);
      this.loadData(data.route);
    });
  }
```

My problem is I need the `queryParams` and the `params` subscriptions to complete and assign the public values *before* the `data` subscription takes place (`queryParams` and `params` can complete in any order as they don't have dependencies on each other).

In all of the examples I've seen, they show where each subscription is dependent on the previous and uses the values of the previous (passed down as variables). If I was using pure functions, I could possibly see where this is beneficial, but given that the code-behind in Angular also functions as a ViewModel, I'm simply setting public variables and then referencing them in the `setProvider` and `loadData` functions.

**The below code works** (basically chaining pipes), but given my limited knowledge on all that there is Rxjs, I wasn't sure if there was a cleaner, more efficient way to write this. It seems rather silly to return an observable just to use its values in the next chain of the pipe.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(concatMap((query: any) => {
        if (!!query.page) {
          if (query.page <= 1) this.skip = 0;
          else this.skip = (query.page - 1) * this.limit;
        }

        return this.activatedRoute.params;
      })).pipe(concatMap((params: any) => {
        this.filter = params.filter;
        this.term = params.term;
        this.year = params.year;
        this.month = params.month;

        return this.activatedRoute.data;
      })).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.setProvider(data.route);
        this.loadData(data.route);
      });
  }
```

Thanks everyone!

### Edit

The below also works using `concat`:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    concat(
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe((q: any) : any => {
        let query = q.getValue();

        if (!!query.page) {
          if (query.page <= 1) this.skip = 0;
          else this.skip = (query.page - 1) * this.limit;
        }
      }),
      this.activatedRoute.params.pipe((p: any) : any => {
        let params = p.getValue();

        this.filter = params.filter;
        this.term = params.term;
        this.year = params.year;
        this.month = params.month;
      }),
      this.activatedRoute.data.pipe((d: any) : any => {
        let data = d.getValue();

        this.setProvider(data.route);
        this.loadData(data.route);
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it has to be done with manual subscriptions I would combine latest for the activatedRoute `queryParams`, `params` and `data` and with a basic if check run the last part when appropriate.

Something like this maybe:

```js
    combineLatest(
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams,
      this.activatedRoute.params,
      this.activatedRoute.data,
      (queryParams: Params, params: Params, data: any) => ({
        queryParams
        params,
        data,
      })
    ).subscribe((res: {queryParams: Params; params: Params; data: any }) => {
     
      if (!!queryParams.page && queryParams.page <= 1) {
       this.skip = 0;
      } else {
        this.skip = (queryParams.page - 1) * this.limit;
      }

     if (params) {
      this.filter = params.filter;
      this.term = params.term;
      this.year = params.year;
      this.month = params.month;
     }

      if (queryParams && params && data) {
        this.setProvider(data.route);
        this.loadData(data.route);
      }
    });
```

Also try to enforce strong types if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Jooseph. Question: I made an edit to my post using `concat`. Out of curiosity, how does `combineLatest` compare with `concat`? Is there one that's better than the other? (Again, there's so much Rxjs I haven't learned.) Thanks again!

Comment: With concat all three will have to complete before contents are run and they are run in order. CombineLatest will run contents when either one of three emits something (it could be instant with Subjects). So if your application has time and UI doesn't depend much on these results then concat would actually be less wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Joosep for the answer. I've updated it due to the his recommended function signature being deprecated.

Here's the updated version:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    combineLatest([
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams,
      this.activatedRoute.params,
      this.activatedRoute.data,
    ]).subscribe(
      ([queryParams, params, data]) => {

        if (!!queryParams['page'] && queryParams['page'] <= 1) {
          this.skip = 0;
        } else {
          this.skip = (queryParams['page'] - 1) * this.limit;
        }

        if (params) {
          this.filter = params['filter'];
          this.term = params['term'];
          this.year = params['year'];
          this.month = params['month'];
        }

        if (queryParams && params && data) {
          this.setProvider(data['route']);
          this.loadData(data['route']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```